# Are there any recommended practices or tools for testing Next.js applications, including both unit tests and end-to-end (e2e) tests?

Tags: next.js

I'm experiencing difficulties with end-to-end testing in my Next.js application. Are there any tools or frameworks that are commonly used for end-to-end testing in the Next.js ecosystem?

I tried to test my APIs for fetching data and perform end-to-end testing, but unfortunately, I encountered some errors along the way. I'm currently in the process of troubleshooting and investigating the cause of these issues. I believe that thorough testing is crucial to ensure the reliability and functionality of my application, so I'm determined to resolve these errors and make my tests successful. I may seek guidance from the testing community or explore relevant documentation to better understand and address the specific errors I'm facing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.